# Function pointer (to other kernel) as kernel arg in CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, function-pointers, gpgpu

With dynamic parallelism in CUDA, you can launch kernels on the GPU side, starting from a certain version. I have a wrapper function that takes a pointer to the kernel I want to use, and it either does this on the CPU for older devices, or on the GPU for newer devices. For the fallback path it's fine, for the GPU it's not and says the memory alignment is incorrect.

Is there a way to do this in CUDA (7)? Are there some lower-level calls that will give me a pointer address that's correct on the GPU?

The code is below, the template "TFunc" is an attempt to get the compiler to do something different, but I've tried it strongly typed as well.

```
template <typename TFunc, typename... TArgs>
__global__ void Test(TFunc func, int count, TArgs... args)
{
#if defined(__CUDA_ARCH__) && (__CUDA_ARCH__ >= 320)
    (*func)<< <1, 1 >> >(args...);
#else
    printf("What are you doing here!?\n");
#endif
}

template <typename... TArgs>
__host__ void Iterate(void(*kernel)(TArgs...), const systemInfo *sysInfo, int count, TArgs... args)
{
    if(sysInfo->getCurrentDevice()->compareVersion("3.2") > 0)
    {
        printf("Iterate on GPU\n");
        Test << <1, 1 >> >(kernel, count, args...);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Iterate on CPU\n");
        Test << <1, 1 >> >(kernel, count, args...);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd be very surprised if there was a way to make this work. It *might* be possible via the device side `cudaLaunchDevice` function, but even then I think you might need to create a stub function with a hardcoded kernel launch for each kernel in a given codebase (this is how the runtime API works on the host under the hood).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** 
At the time that I originally wrote this answer, I believe the statements were correct: it was not possible to take a kernel address in host code.  However I believe something has changed in CUDA since then, and so now (in CUDA 8, and maybe prior) it is possible to take a *kernel* address in host code (it's still not possible to take the address of a `__device__` function in host code, however.)

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**:

It seems like this question comes up from time to time, although the [previous examples I can think of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26738079/cuda-kernel-with-function-pointer-and-variadic-templates) have to do with calling `__device__` functions instead of `__global__` functions.

In general it's illegal to take the address of a device entity (variable, function) in host code.

One possible method to work around this (although the utility of this is not clear to me; it seems like there would be simpler dispatch mechanisms) is to extract the device address needed "in device code" and return that value to the host, for dispatch usage.  In this case, I am creating a simple example that extracts the needed device addresses into `__device__` variables, but you could also write a kernel to do this setup (i.e. to "give me a pointer address that's correct on the GPU" in your words).

Here's a rough worked example, building on the code you have shown:

```
$ cat t746.cu
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void ckernel1(){

  printf("hello1\n");
}
__global__ void ckernel2(){

  printf("hello2\n");
}
__global__ void ckernel3(){

  printf("hello3\n");
}

__device__ void (*pck1)() = ckernel1;
__device__ void (*pck2)() = ckernel2;
__device__ void (*pck3)() = ckernel3;

template <typename TFunc, typename... TArgs>
__global__ void Test(TFunc func, int count, TArgs... args)
{
#if defined(__CUDA_ARCH__) && (__CUDA_ARCH__ >= 350)
    (*func)<< <1, 1 >> >(args...);
#else
    printf("What are you doing here!?\n");
#endif
}

template <typename... TArgs>
__host__ void Iterate(void(*kernel)(TArgs...), const int sysInfo, int count, TArgs... args)
{
    if(sysInfo >= 350)
    {
        printf("Iterate on GPU\n");
        Test << <1, 1 >> >(kernel, count, args...);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Iterate on CPU\n");
        Test << <1, 1 >> >(kernel, count, args...);
    }
}


int main(){

  void (*h_ckernel1)();
  void (*h_ckernel2)();
  void (*h_ckernel3)();
  cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&h_ckernel1, pck1, sizeof(void *));
  cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&h_ckernel2, pck2, sizeof(void *));
  cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&h_ckernel3, pck3, sizeof(void *));
  Iterate(h_ckernel1, 350, 1);
  Iterate(h_ckernel2, 350, 1);
  Iterate(h_ckernel3, 350, 1);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  return 0;
}

$ nvcc -std=c++11 -arch=sm_35 -o t746 t746.cu -rdc=true -lcudadevrt
$ cuda-memcheck ./t746
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
Iterate on GPU
Iterate on GPU
Iterate on GPU
hello1
hello2
hello3
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

The above (`__device__` variable) method probably can't be made to work with templated child kernels, but it might be possible to create a templated "extractor" kernel that returns the address of a (instantiated) templated child kernel.  A rough idea of the "extractor" `setup_kernel` method is given in the previous answer I linked.  Here's a rough example of the templated child kernel/extractor kernel method:

```
$ cat t746.cu
#include <stdio.h>

template <typename T>
__global__ void ckernel1(T *data){

  int my_val = (int)(*data+1);
  printf("hello: %d \n", my_val);
}
template <typename TFunc, typename... TArgs>
__global__ void Test(TFunc func, int count, TArgs... args)
{
#if defined(__CUDA_ARCH__) && (__CUDA_ARCH__ >= 350)
    (*func)<< <1, 1 >> >(args...);
#else
    printf("What are you doing here!?\n");
#endif
}

template <typename... TArgs>
__host__ void Iterate(void(*kernel)(TArgs...), const int sysInfo, int count, TArgs... args)
{
    if(sysInfo >= 350)
    {
        printf("Iterate on GPU\n");
        Test << <1, 1 >> >(kernel, count, args...);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Iterate on CPU\n");
        Test << <1, 1 >> >(kernel, count, args...);
    }
}

template <typename T>
__global__ void extractor(void (**kernel)(T *)){

  *kernel = ckernel1<T>;
}

template <typename T>
void run_test(T init){

  void (*h_ckernel1)(T *);
  void (**d_ckernel1)(T *);
  T *d_data;
  cudaMalloc(&d_ckernel1, sizeof(void *));
  cudaMalloc(&d_data, sizeof(T));
  cudaMemcpy(d_data, &init, sizeof(T), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  extractor<<<1,1>>>(d_ckernel1);
  cudaMemcpy((void *)&h_ckernel1, (void *)d_ckernel1, sizeof(void *), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  Iterate(h_ckernel1, 350, 1, d_data);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  cudaFree(d_ckernel1);
  cudaFree(d_data);
  return;
}

int main(){

  run_test(1);
  run_test(2.0f);

  return 0;
}

$ nvcc -std=c++11 -arch=sm_35 -o t746 t746.cu -rdc=true -lcudadevrt
$ cuda-memcheck ./t746
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
Iterate on GPU
hello: 2
Iterate on GPU
hello: 3
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```